# Java regex to jquery regex conversion

Tags: java, jquery, regex

I have below regex in my Java code

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9,!#&.\\/:()_\\- ]{1,256}+$
```

I need identical regex for my jquery validation.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: it should work for both `JAVA` and `JavaScript`

Comment: `^[a-zA-Z0-9,!#&.\\/:()_\\\- ]{1,256}$`

Comment: i thought same about it but for java its working but jquery its not seems working :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regex expressions are language-agnostic. So a regex that works with Java should work with jQuery as well.

Comment: @ketan Thanks for clarifying :)